# C: How to read a jpg from a file and save it?

Tags: c, file, download, jpeg

I am having some trouble reading a jpg file and saving it. I want to implement a file sharing system between a client and server and I am unable to even read a jpg and save it on the same process. Here is what I have so far

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *buffer;
    FILE *picture;
    FILE *newPicture;
    struct stat st;
    long fileSize = 0;


    picture = fopen("PATH/root/game-of-thrones-poster.jpg", "rb");
    fstat(picture, &st);
    fileSize = st.st_size;
    if(fileSize > 0) {
        buffer = malloc(fileSize);

        if(read(picture, buffer, fileSize) < 0) {
            printf("Error reading file");
        }
        fclose(picture);

        newPicture = fopen("PATH/root/new.jpg", "wb");
        write(newPicture, buffer, fileSize);
    }
    free(buffer);
}
```

When it tries to read the file, it tells me that fileSize is 0.

Comment: if `fopen` returns NULL, you should display `errno` perhaps with `perror` (or using `strerror(errno)`); and you should also compile with `-Wall` because your use of `fstat` is wrong (should be `fstat(fileno(picture),&st)` and you better call `memset(&st, 0, sizeof(st))` before....); BTW why use `read` instead of `fread` ?

Comment: Actually, your code probably don't compile.

Comment: The you should enable warnings (so compile with `gcc -Wall -g`), and include `<stdio.h>` and  `<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>`, `<unistd.h>`, I'm sure the compiler would complain (i.e. gives warnings which you should resolve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> fstat() is identical to stat(), except that the file to be stat-ed is
>   specified by the file descriptor fd.

You are passing `FILE *`, `fstat` expects an `int`

Comment: I am new to C, I thought fstat requires a file descriptor?

Comment: A file descriptor is an integer given by `open`. But `fopen` returns a `FILE` handle (which is not the same, and is a pointer).